How to get a multiline textInput in Expo / React native
I am using Expo Go and React Native. I did spend endless hours with TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Input (from react native elements) and ScrollView to get a one line text input field on Android and iOS. I learned that in most cases and luckily for me KeyboardAvoidingView is not needed on Android.
Now would like to enhance (or better replace) my text input field. It should not scroll horizontally, but instead vertically. It should add roughly four lines of text, if the text gets that long. After that, it only scrolls down further. The cursor never disappears behind the keyboard.
Here is a video of what I want (taken from the signal app)
The obvious properties of textInput: multiline, scrollEnabled and numberOfLines are not available for both OS and they don't do exactly what I want. Most of my experiments let the cursor disappear behind the keyboard (at least on iOS).
Is there any npm package, that I could use or any suggestion how to achieve this quickly?
